# Grails JMS ActiveMQ, Virtual Topics, messageSelector

Tags: grails, jms, virtual, messaging

We're currently using Grails 2.3.4 with ActiveMQ 5.7.0 and JMS Plugin 1.2, to successfully receive message maps by queues.

Now we want to switch to a "virtual topic" based scenario - and fail miserably, when it comes to receiving by Grails... 
Standard Camel tests work, so the sending side seems ok.

Addendum: we use "selector-aware" configuration.

E. g. for a "queue-like" access to the "virtual topics" we need to set the "static messageSelector", but accessing the ActiveMQ by JMX never shows any value for the selector.

Has anyone had any experience using the **ActiveMQ "virtual topic"** with Grails!?

In addition, just recently I found that "grails-jms /src/groovy/grails/plugin/jms/listener/ListenerConfig.groovy" shows some strange code (see below).
Is there some Groovy woodoo at work or is it just an error?

```
def registerListenerContainer(beanBuilder) {
    beanBuilder.with {
        "${listenerContainerBeanName}"() {
            it.parent = ref(containerParent + JmsListenerContainerAbstractBeanDefinitionBuilder.nameSuffix)
            it.'abstract' = false
            it.destroyMethod = "destroy"

            destinationName = this.destinationName

            pubSubDomain = topic
            // (( ????????????
            if (messageSelector) {
                messageSelector = messageSelector
            }
            // )) ????????????

            messageListener = ref(listenerAdapterBeanName)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help, comment, thought, whatsoever...

Comment: I can't help much here, but I can explain the bean definition. It looks like a no-op but inside a bean definition nearly every property get and set, and method call is handed by the builder in its missing-method and missing-property handling. All of those inner expressions will set properties, calling the setter that corresponds to the property name on the left, and using the expression on the right as the value (effectively `bean.setMessageSelector(this.messageSelector)`) where `messageSelector` is a real variable defined at the top of `ListenerConfig`. So if that's set externally, it be used

Comment: Thanks, I feared thusly...
Then it looks like that there is an error in the JMS Plugin - I can now create a messageSelector by using plain beans in resources.groovy in Grails, but the consumer created by the JMS Plugin never shows the static messageSelector that I set.